# jquery autocomplete, How to populate to the HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to get the HTML to show the suggestions returned from my autocomplete ajax query. I've tried to find tutorials for this but none actually explain how the data goes from the JSON sent by the php to the jquery and then to the HTML.

php function:

```
function autoCompany($keyword){
global $DBH;


$stmt = "SELECT companyID, companyName FROM Company WHERE companyName LIKE '%' ? '%'";

try{
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($stmt);
    $STH->bindParam(1, $keyword);
    $STH->execute();

    if($STH->RowCount() > 0){

            $suggestions = array(); 
        while($row = $STH->fetch()){
            $suggestions[] = array(
            "label" => $row['companyName'],
            "value" => $row['companyID']
            );
        }

        echo json_encode(array('suggestion' => $suggestions));
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
    }

}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage() . "autoCompany";
}
}
```

I know the data is being sent over correctly:

```
suggestion: [{value:Test Company, data:1}, {value:Testing Test, data:4}]
 0: {value:Test Company, data:1}
 1: {value:Testing Test, data:4}
```

but how do you get the data to output in a dropdown list?

my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">AutoComplete</label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete" class="form-control col-md-10" style="float: left;" />
   <div class="autocomplete-suggestions">
       <div class="autocomplete-suggestion autocomplete-selected">...</div>
       <div class="autocomplete-suggestion">...</div>
       <div class="autocomplete-suggestion">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My autocomplete jquery:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: 'Admin/ajax.admin.php',
  paramName: "autoCompany",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  onSelect: function (suggestion) {
      alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
  }success: function (data) {
  response($.map(data.d, function (i) {
      return {
          //From Here to DDL?
      }
     }))
  },
 });
```

Comment: Is your code working or you just need to know how it works?

Comment: just need to know how. I don't understand how to go from the `JSON` that my php returns to the `divs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you area looking for it to populate the dropdown that it creates on its own you need to map your JSON data like so.

```
response($.map(data.d, function (i) {
      return {
          label: i.value,
          value: i.data
      }
}
```

Comment: When I try this nothing happens. I'll I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined `

Comment: `data.d` should probably be `data.suggestion`, you could set up a fiddle if you need more help

Comment: found the issue. I was returning `suggestion` and needed to return `suggestions`. Thank you for your help